# max-width versus max-height in Google Chrome

Tags: css

I am trying to resize an image using only CSS, based on its container height. Here is the code and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/navyflower/GBgFh/2/).

```
<div id="first">
<img src="http://www.helpinghomelesscats.com/images/cat1.jpg" width=360 height=360>  
</div>​

#first {
    height: 100px;
}
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Setting max-height is not working in Chrome. The image is flattened. In Firefox and IE it looks OK.
However, setting max-width is working in all browsers.

```
#first {
    width: 100px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Can someone tell me, how to achieve correct result for max-height, which would work also in Chrome?

​

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, Chrome doesn't seem to be overriding the fixed width with "auto", even though the Inspector says it does.

The easiest solution is to just not specify the `width` and `height` attributes of the image.